# I try to show a name in the url in react

Tags: reactjs, url, parameters, react-router

I try to show a name in the url, but no matter what I try it just doesn't work.
So I have a component in react which shows the results of students separately.
I can select them with radio buttons.

I've tryed using params, Links etc. but i can't get the name in the url.
can someone help me?

It think i'm trying the wrong way.
I have my react app working, only that last piece of the puzzle doesn't work.

```
This my Container.js

const studentData = require('./Studentdata.json')
const wincTheme = require('./theme/WincTheme')


const Container = () => {
    const [barRating, setBarRating] = useState({ name: "difficult-and-fun" })
    const [lineRating, setLineRating] = useState({ name: "difficult-and-fun" })
    const [allStudentData, setAllStudentData] = useState({ name: "Evelyn" })



    const handleStudentChange = e => {
        const { value } = e.target
        setAllStudentData({ name: value })
    }

    const handleChangeBarRating = e => {
        const { value } = e.target
        setBarRating({ name: value })
    }
    const handleChangeLineRating = e => {
        const { value } = e.target
        setLineRating({ name: value })
    }

    return (
        <main className="main">
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/">
                    <Redirect to="/home" />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/home">
                    <Home
                        studentData={studentData}
                        wincTheme={wincTheme}
                        barRating={barRating}
                        lineRating={lineRating}
                        handleChangeBarRating={handleChangeBarRating}
                        handleChangeLineRating={handleChangeLineRating} />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/students">
                    <Students
                        studentData={studentData}
                        wincTheme={wincTheme}
                        handleStudentChange={handleStudentChange}
                        allStudentData={allStudentData}/>
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        </main >
    )
}

export default Container
```

```
this is my Students.js

const Students = (props) => {


    const displayOneStudent = () => {
    let onestudent = props.studentData.student.find(student => {
            return student.name === props.allStudentData.name
        })
        return onestudent
}
    
    const assignmentStudents = displayOneStudent().assignments
    const wincTheme = props.wincTheme.default

    const assignmentRatingStudents = assignmentStudents.map(person => ({
        assignment: person.name,
        difficultyRating: person.difficultyRating,
        funRating: person.funRating,
        label: `Opdracht ${person.name}, 
            difficultyRating: ${person.difficultyRating},  
            funRating: ${person.funRating}`
    }))
    // console.log(assignmentRatingStudents)
    
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="radiobuttons-students">
                <label className="custom-radio">
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    className="custom-radio"
                    name='allStudentData'
                    value="Evelyn"
                    checked={props.allStudentData.name === "Evelyn"}
                    onChange={props.handleStudentChange}
                    />
                    <span className="radio-btn">
                        <i className="icon-check"></i>
                    <div className="hobbies-icon">
                    <img 
                        src={Evelyn}
                        alt="new"
                        height="50px"
                        />
                    <h3>Evelyn</h3>
                    </div>
                </span>
                </label>
                <label className="custom-radio">
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    className="custom-radio"
                    name='allStudentData'
                    value="Aranka"
                    checked={props.allStudentData.name === "Aranka"}
                    onChange={props.handleStudentChange}
                    />
                <span className="radio-btn">
                    <i className="icon-check"></i>
                    <div className="hobbies-icon">
                    <img 
                        src={Aranka}
                        alt="new"
                        height="50px"
                        />
                    <h3>Aranka</h3>
                    </div>
                </span>
                </label>
                <label className="custom-radio">
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    className="custom-radio"
                    name='allStudentData'
                    value="Floris"
                    checked={props.allStudentData.name === "Floris"}
                    onChange={props.handleStudentChange}
                    />
                    <span className="radio-btn">
                    <i className="icon-check"></i>
                    <div className="hobbies-icon">
                    <img 
                        src={Floris}
                        alt="new"
                        height="50px"
                        />
                    <h3>Floris</h3>
                    </div>
                </span>
                </label>
                <label className="custom-radio">
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    className="custom-radio"
                    name='allStudentData'
                    value="Hector"
                    checked={props.allStudentData.name === "Hector"}
                    onChange={props.handleStudentChange}
                    />
                    <span className="radio-btn">
                    <i className="icon-check"></i>
                    <div className="hobbies-icon">
                    <img 
                        src={Hector}
                        alt="new"
                        height="50px"
                        />
                    <h3>Hector</h3>
                    </div>
                </span>
                </label>
                <label className="custom-radio">
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    className="custom-radio"
                    name='allStudentData'
                    value="Martina"
                    checked={props.allStudentData.name === "Martina"}
                    onChange={props.handleStudentChange}
                    />
                    <span className="radio-btn">
                    <i className="icon-check"></i>
                    <div className="hobbies-icon">
                    <img 
                        src={Martina}
                        alt="new"
                        height="50px"
                        />
                    <h3>Martina</h3>
                    </div>
                </span>
                </label>
                <label className="custom-radio">
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    className="custom-radio"
                    name='allStudentData'
                    value="Maurits"
                    checked={props.allStudentData.name === "Maurits"}
                    onChange={props.handleStudentChange}
                    />
                    <span className="radio-btn">
                    <i className="icon-check"></i>
                    <div className="hobbies-icon">
                    <img 
                        src={Maurits}
                        alt="new"
                        height="50px"
                        />
                    <h3>Maurits</h3>
                    </div>
                </span>
                </label>
                <label className="custom-radio">
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    className="custom-radio"
                    name='allStudentData'
                    value="Rahima"
                    checked={props.allStudentData.name === "Rahima"}
                    onChange={props.handleStudentChange}
                    />
                    <span className="radio-btn">
                    <i className="icon-check"></i>
                    <div className="hobbies-icon">
                    <img 
                        src={Rahima}
                        alt="new"
                        height="50px"
                        />
                    <h3>Rahima</h3>
                    </div>
                </span>
                </label>
                <label className="custom-radio">
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    className="custom-radio"
                    name='allStudentData'
                    value="Sandra"
                    checked={props.allStudentData.name === "Sandra"}
                    onChange={props.handleStudentChange}
                    />
                    <span className="radio-btn">
                    <i className="icon-check"></i>
                    <div className="hobbies-icon">
                    <img 
                        src={Sandra}
                        alt="new"
                        height="50px"
                        />
                    <h3>Sandra</h3>
                    </div>
                </span>
                </label>
                <label className="custom-radio">
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    className="custom-radio"
                    name='allStudentData'
                    value="Wietske"
                    checked={props.allStudentData.name === "Wietske"}
                    onChange={props.handleStudentChange}
                    />
                    <span className="radio-btn">
                    <i className="icon-check"></i>
                    <div className="hobbies-icon">
                    <img 
                        src={Wietske}
                        alt="new"
                        height="50px"
                        />
                    <h3>Wietske</h3>
                    </div>
                </span>
                </label>
                <label className="custom-radio">
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    className="custom-radio"
                    name='allStudentData'
                    value="Storm"
                    checked={props.allStudentData.name === "Storm"}
                    onChange={props.handleStudentChange}
                    />
                    <span className="radio-btn">
                    <i className="icon-check"></i>
                    <div className="hobbies-icon">
                    <img 
                        src={Storm}
                        alt="new"
                        height="50px"
                        />
                    <h3>Storm</h3>
                    </div>
                </span>
                </label>
                </div>
                <h1 className="student">{props.allStudentData.name}</h1>
            <VictoryChart domainPadding={15} theme={wincTheme}>
                <VictoryGroup offset={5}>
                    <VictoryBar
                        labelComponent={<VictoryTooltip />}
                        data={assignmentRatingStudents}
                        x="assignment"
                        y="difficultyRating"
                        tickValues={[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
                        tickFormat={assignmentRatingStudents.map(avg => avg.assignment)} />
                    <VictoryBar
                        labelComponent={<VictoryTooltip />}
                        data={assignmentRatingStudents}
                        x="assignment"
                        y="funRating"
                        tickValues={[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
                        tickFormat={assignmentRatingStudents.map(avg => avg.assignment)} />
                </VictoryGroup>
                <VictoryAxis
                    tickValues={[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
                    tickFormat={assignmentRatingStudents.map(avg => avg.assignment)} />
                <VictoryAxis dependentAxis />
            </VictoryChart >
        </div>
    )
}
export default Students
```

Comment: Can you show us when you try to modify the url in your code, please ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the URL of your route is not dynamic. You should use the colon before students in the path.

`<Route path="/:students">`

Once the route is dynamic you should push the name in the URL. You can do that using useHistory hook and pushing the name in an onClick event, for example.
Something like:

```js
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const ParentComponent = () => {
  
  const history = useHistory();
  //other variables

  return(
    <div>
      {studentsList.map((student, stdIdx) =>
        <div 
          key={stdIdx}
          onClick={() => history.push(`/${student.name}`)}
         >
          {studentData.map etc.}
        </div>
      )}
   </div>
  );
}
```